# Retain filled fields in the form on reload/refresh in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add the feature that the filled form field values are retained in the form on page reload. Is there a way to to this. Will `vm.$forceUpdate()` solve this issue? Please help me solve this issue

```
   <template>
     <v-card class="mb-12">
       <v-form :model='user' class="content-padding" ref='pdfInputs'>
            <div class="section-header">
              User
            </div>
            <v-container fluid>
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right info-align">
                  <v-text-field required
                    label='User Full Name​'
                    v-model='user.user_full_name'>
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-left info-align">
                  <v-text-field
                    label='Street Address'
                    v-model='user.user_address'
                    required>
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-form>
         </v-card>
     </template>  


<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      user: {
        user_full_name: '',
        user_address: []
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: using `$vm.$forceUpdate` resolves you problem?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos I was asking if that would solve this issue? If yes, how can I use it.?

Comment: use `localstorage` to store your form state and retrieve it on load

Answer (score 1):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) for persistent storage.

You should either `watch` for changes on `user` or stop using `v-model` and use `v-bind` and `v-on:change` to be able to catch changes to your models and save them.

Then on `mounted` or other lifecycle methods you need to read from your persistent medium and populate `user`.

Going forward, if you encounter this need more and more, you could use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store your data and use the `mutations` to save to persistent medium. You should also populate the store at startup from localStorage/indexedDB.

Comment: localStorage sounds like a plan. I have other fields in my table too and to maintain consistence of the code I can't remove v-model. 
Can you help me with the implementation of localStorage with my code?